# Reading data from the end of disk in C

Tags: c, ubuntu

I try to use crypto key for decrypting disk in Ubuntu 16 and I want read it from the end of disk just as raw data without creating any file for security reason, i.e. like dd does in way

```
sudo dd if=some_disk bs=1 skip=end_of_disk - keysize count=keysize
```

So, I wrote a test program

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

unsigned long long disksize(char *drivename)
{
  int fd;
  unsigned long long numblocks=0;

  fd = open(drivename, O_RDONLY);
  ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE64, &numblocks);
  close(fd);
  return numblocks;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int fd;
  FILE *device;
  int keySize = 2048;
  int count;
  unsigned char *block;
  unsigned long long endOfDisk=disksize(argv[1]);
  unsigned long long startFrom = endOfDisk - keySize;
  block = calloc(keySize, sizeof(char));
//  fd=open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_DIRECT);
  device = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  long res = fseek(device, startFrom, SEEK_SET);
  perror("\nSeeking error:");
  fread(block, 1, keySize, device);
  fclose(device);
  printf("\nDevice Size: %lld\n", endOfDisk);
  printf("\nReading data starting from: %lld\n", startFrom);
  for(count = 0; count < keySize; count++){
      printf("%c", block[count]); 
  }
  free(block);
}
```

It works good on small disks, say, on boot partition or USB stick with capacity of 1Gb, but when I try to get key from, say, 4Gb USB stick, I can't: program prints something beyond key area on disk and **perror** shows "Invalid argument" as result of **fseek**. It looks like **fseek** can't set pointer right and I don't understand why:

```
fdisk -l some_disk
```

shows exactly the same disk size as **endOfDisk** from given program.

P.S. As someone can see from a couple of rudiments, I tried lseek too with exactly the same result printing exactly the same info instead of stored on disk key.

Comment: Holy include madness, Batman!

Comment: usually some error comes from confusion about address/size to be in blocks, sectors, bytes, pages; you can "spy" your program with strace to see if it reads at the correct position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE64, &numblocks)` return size in 512-byte blocks, `fseek()` expect offset in bytes.
BTW, you can set pointer relative to the end of disk without knowing it's size:

```
fseek(device, -keySize, SEEK_END);
```

Comment: PS: "Invalid argument" may not be related to fseek() if it succeed. `errno` is relevant only if a function returned error code.

Comment: Thank You very much, shame on me not use SEEK_END.

Comment: But I still don't understand  ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE64, &numblocks) thing: fdisk shows for given disk **7,5 GiB, 8004304896 bytes, 15633408 sectors**; my test shows **Device size: 8004304896** and **Reading data from: 8004302848**. Keeping in mind latter is an argument for fseek, why that thing doesn't like it?

Comment: Unlike BLKGETSIZE, BLKGETSIZE64 returns size in bytes, so code is correct. Problem is calling perror without checking res.

Comment: Oops, i was wrong about 512-byte blocks. BLKGETSIZE64 indeed return bytes.
Check value returned by fseek().

Comment: @stark No, I don't think so: **perror** is last minute edit; just **fseek** itself without **res** didn't work, that's why I tried to shed a little light by perror

Comment: @dimich **fseek** returns success (0) or not success (-1). Again, that's why I used perror

Comment: Dump actual data at the end of disk with `dd if=/dev/sdX bs=1 count=2048 skip=8004302848 | hexdump -C` where /dev/sdX is your disk. Is it the same as expected?

Comment: sure, that's what I started from. As summary: dd works smoothly, fseek backward from  the end of device works smoothly, fseek to given position in bytes works for small media only (up to 1 Gb). Not sure what about 2Gb because of absence such media. but 4Gb doesn't work definitely

Comment: Is your system 32-bit? For 32-bit targets long is 32-bit, thus fseek() can't accept more than 2Gb offset. Use fseeko() instead, but don't forget to compile with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`

Comment: Well, that flag is enough, no need for fseeko up to 16 Gb at least. Problem solved, thank You once more for Your help